# Minikube: Nginix ingress controller path rules and connecting from the host OS browser?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I've configured an Ingress controller in Kubernetes and have a question regarding functionality.

```
$ minikube service list
ingress-nginx | ingress-nginx-controller           | http/80      | http://192.168.64.2:30691
```

I'm able to connect and get a response from my web service HTTP API:

```
$ curl --resolve "nr-demo.com:80:$( minikube ip )" -i http://nr-demo.com/api
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 23 Jul 2023 21:56:34 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://undefined:undefined
Vary: Origin
```

However, when I use the following a connection a 404 response is returned:

```
curl http://192.168.64.2:30691/api
```

I'm trying to have two microservices available on the same origin, frontend and backend with different paths using this Ingress rules below.  This way CORS isn't triggered.

First, what is the `curl --resolve` command actually doing?  I don't see port `30691` specified anywhere in the command, so how does it know to establish a connection on that endpoint?

Second, how will I test my application if `curl --resolve` is required for establishing the connection?  For instance, I need to type in `http://192.168.64.2:30691/api` and `http://192.168.64.2:30691/` into a browser address and this curl request is not available.  Is this a feasible way to test a frontend and backend, available on different paths?  Are there other options to allow the browser to work as curl does above?

Thanks

For reference here is the Ingress rules for above:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nr-demo-mean-api-1-ing
spec:
  rules:
    - host: nr-demo.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: nr-demo-mean-api-1-svc-np
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

> First, what is the curl --resolve command actually doing?

The `--resolve` option says, "when you see a connection to `nr.demo.com` on port `80`, then use the ip address returned by `$(minikube ip)` rather than the result of a DNS lookup for `nr.demo.com`.

> I don't see port 30691 specified anywhere in the command, so how does it know to establish a connection on that endpoint?

Access to the ingress service is handled by NAT rules in the minikube container (or virtual machine, if you're not using the Docker driver). I have a Docker-based minikube instance running; inside the container we see:

```
$ docker exec -it minikube iptables -t nat -S
[...]
-A CNI-DN-d53472351adf60f6edddc -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.244.0.5:80
-A CNI-DN-d53472351adf60f6edddc -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.244.0.5:443
[...]
```

This maps requests to the minikube address, for ports 80 and 443, to `10.244.0.5` on the same port (the specific target ip will probably be different for you).

In this case, `10.244.0.5` is the pod running the ingress service:

```
$ k -n ingress-nginx get pod -l app.kubernetes.io/component=controller -o json | jq .items[].status.podIP
"10.244.0.5"
```

So your request for `$(minikube ip):80` hits the NAT rule, which sends it to the nginx pod, where nginx is listening on ports 80 and 443.

> Second, how will I test my application if curl --resolve is required for establishing the connection?

If you want to load these websites in a browser, the easiest solution is to add entries to your `/etc/hosts` file that map the appropriate hostnames to the address of your ingress service.  That is, do something like:

```
echo "$(minikube ip) nr.demo.com" >> /etc/hosts
```

Then you can type `nr.demo.com` into your browser and it will get handled just like your `curl --resolve ...` command line.